# how do I modify css in mui components - accordian?

Tags: css, reactjs

React newbie here. I am using the Accordian component from material-ui and wanting to set the background color and other styling options but am confused as material-ui examples in their docs follow an `export defaulf func...` style vs my codebase follows an `export const` style as below. What is the difference between the two and how do I overcome my styling issue and set a background color for the accordion in below code?

I've tried the following;

```
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';


export interface CProps {
  data: any;
}

export const Cbutes: React.FC<CProps> = ({ data }) => {
  
    return <div>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
     
      
    </div>
};
```

`className="bg-color-blue-500..."` is how I usually style elements with tailwind throughout the app. But doesn't seem to work in this case. I believe I will need to use materialUI styling. Could someone please shed some light or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: does https://github.com/damien-monni/material-ui-tailwind help?

Comment: thanks for the comment @Armihe but I'm wanting to stick to the existing libs without having to complicate. Do you know of a way to even use materialUI styling to change the background color & text colors of these accordians?

Comment: I guess the least affordable action is using classes props provided for a long time by every component

Answer (score 0):

In a case, you don't want to change any infrastructural thing in your project, you can use old `classes` props. The `classes` prop is an object used for overriding or extending the styles applied to the component. See [CSS API](https://mui.com/api/typography/#css) below for more details.

It works with the simple CSS combination so it must not have a problem with the tailwind, but you might need to change your config a little bit if you have a problem with specificity and overriding

Here is an example of the Basic Accordion component.

> CSS possible keys can be found [here](https://mui.com/api/typography/#css).

```
<Accordion
  classes={{
    root: 'lowercase text-gray-500 bg-red-100'
  }}
/>
```